# How to exceed the body's height beyond the view port & have the content centered vertically?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page with vertically centered content (I'm using [this method](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)). I need to use two different page backgrounds. One is assigned to **html** tag and the other one to the **body** tag (it doesn't matter if I'll create div's instead). The first one is a background picture (full width & height of the view port, *fixed, no-repeat*) and the other one is just a pattern, intended to overlay the picture (*repeat*). I tried to use CSS3's multiple backgrounds for this case, but it didn't worked as I intended.

The problem is that when the content exceeds the view port, the **body**'s background covers only the height of the view port. The solution for this is quite simple:

```
body { min-height: 100%; }
```

But it comes with a serious drawback. If I set the *min-height* value while the content doesn't exceed the view port, it won't be vertically centered.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tgvrw3k/) to help you better understand my problem. Don't mind the JavaScript as it does not play any role in this case. I used 1x1 px background images as an example.

Try to toggle the content's height while the body's height is set to *100%* and scroll down. You will see what I'm talking about. You can fix that by toggling the body's height, but as soon as you toggle the content's height back to *auto* it won't be centered vertically any more.

I want the body's background to cover the full page height and have the content positioned in the middle no matter if the content fits in the view port or not. I've tried to achieve that for several hours and I failed, so maybe some of you know something that I don't and could help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0tgvrw3k/2/)

I avoided your problem by making the .block div the size of your screen by fixed positioning. After this I used the .block div to scroll the elements inside. Hope this solves your problem ;).

```
.block {/*made .block fullscreen size so you cannot scroll the page anymore, but scroll this div instead*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: Well, I applied your solution to my page and it works just as I wanted it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don not need < IE9 support, you can use transforms to do that.

http://jsfiddle.net/0tgvrw3k/1/

Basically you don't need the `.block` and make the vertical alignment using top, left, and transform. You need `position: fixed;`, as `position: absolute;` will make the viewport scroll.

Please do not forget to prefix the `transform` with -webkit-, -moz-, -ms- and -o-

Comment: The RMo's solution works best for me, though I appreciate your effort. Thank you